# Два почти одинаковых предложения, но нужна ли запятая в одном из них?

Tags: запятые

Сейчас я вам объясню свой вопрос.
Я знаю о правиле общего члена и что если он присутствует в начале, то запятая не ставится между неоднородными предложениями. Но у меня сомнения, что нужна запятая во втором.

Вечером Дмитрий вернётся и мы все будем ждать вас в кабинете.
Вечером Дмитрий вернётся(,) и мы все будем ждать вас в *его* кабинете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятую не нужно ставить в таком предложении: ***Вечером Дмитрий вернется и мы соберемся в его кабинете.***

Коммуникативная ситуация участникам разговора понятна: встреча состоится именно вечером, потому что Дмитрий к этому времени вернется. Когда именно начнется встреча, будет сообщено дополнительно.

Поэтому наречие ***вечером*** относится к обоим простым предложениям (его не нужно повторять дважды), оно **объединяет** эти предложения. Запятая между ними не ставится, произношение **без подчеркнутой паузы**.

Также обратим внимание на то, что предложения должны быть **достаточны компактны**, чтобы их можно было объединить в одну фразу и прочитать ее соответствующим образом. Если это распространенные и осложненные предложения, то правило к таким предложениям не применяется.

Вот смысл этого правила, в нем нет ничего формального. **Только контексту, по ситуации** можно определить наличие общего  элемента.

Если же предложения придуманы, не отражают конкретную ситуацию, не имеют контекста, то и **разбирать их нет смысла.**

Когда этот Дмитрий приедет, с какого времени общественность начнет его ждать — всё это неясно. Да и структура приведенных предложений такова, что **их в принципе сложно объединить** и привести к одной фонетической фразе. Чтобы понять это, желательно внимательно прочитать примеры из правила Розенталя — там предложения вполне компактны.

Comment: Общий элемент хорош, когда есть однородность (см. примеры Розенталя). Почти во всех случаях части можно поменять местами. А здесь же вторая часть является следствием первой, и это лучше показать пунктуационно. Иначе они могут начать ждать в кабинете Дмитрия до его прихода. Вряд ли это задумывалось. У меня ударение на слово "*вернётся*", а в одну фразу читается плохо.

Comment: Откуда у вас эти сведения?  Даже если можно поменять, то вряд ли это всегда обязательно, короче говоря, ваша точка зрения должна быть доказана. А вот то, что вы беретесь анализировать предложения с неясной семантикой, не есть хорошо (этого и доказывать не нужно). Всегда имейте дело с реальными, а не выдуманными текстами.

Comment: Сведения из примеров Розенталя. Говорю, что **обычно** они меняются. А если есть следствие, то ставят знак и есть пауза. Последнее не понял. Мне в этом предложении всё ясно. Очевидно, что будут ждать после прихода Дмитрия вместе с ним самим, так как кабинет его. Есть задача, и её нужно как-то решить. Менять предложение нет "полномочий", если не спрашивается о редактировании.

Comment: Можете считать, что себя вы убедили, но только не меня. Меня же вы не слышите. Если предложение придумано, то у него нет контекста и ясной ситуации. Это всё, что я могу сказать о Дмитрии и его приходе. А разбирать выдуманные уже вами подробности уж точно не имеет смысла.

Comment: И что, браковать вопрос из-за этого? Вот доступный пример: *Он сделает уроки, и мы пойдём гулять [все вместе].* Тоже неясно? Это никак не перечисление несвязанных событий.

Comment: Ладно, я согласна. Когда сделаете уроки, то идите гулять. Что касается вопроса, то я просто высказала свое мнение. И даже вас (с вашим ответом) не комментировала, пока вы не напросились сами.

Comment: Просто я в своём ответе допускаю ваш вариант, а вы мой отрицаете. Кто-то может подумать, что правы вы, а я, соответственно, нет. А вы-то даже смысл предложения не поняли. Говорю по факту.

Comment: Нет у него смысла. А вот вы не понимаете, что такое коммуникативная ситуация. На самом деле происходят какие-то события, планируются мероприятия, участники  владеют определенной информацией. Так бывает в романах. А ваше предложение ниоткуда.  Рассуждать о нем - только время терять. Но и это еще не всё. Главный негатив вашего ответа  в том, что вы учите окружающих не понимать язык. Он у вас не живой, а механический, язык-робот. Всё теперь, надеюсь,  понятно?

Comment: Вы предлагаете на ответы с неточным смыслом не отвечать? Но вы же ответили... Вполне коммуникативная ситуация: *он закончит то-то, и все вместе сделаем следующее*. Не думаю, что авторы вопросов станут выдумывать предложения, ниоткуда не взятые.

Comment: Я его заменила элементарным предложением, когда смысл предельно  ясен: оба события состоятся вечером. Кто придумывает? Есть авторы, которые хотят разобраться в какой-то теме, но примеры берут не из книг, а выдумывают предложения сами. А это ошибка. Нельзя изучать грамматику и правописание по своим примерам, они должны быть взяты из литературы. Мне это приходилось говорить часто, поэтому это не единичный случай.

Answer (score 2):

Связывать ли вторую часть со словом (фразой) из первой части, делая его общим, — часто решает автор.

Но тут больше следственные отношения (запятая нужна):
*Вечером Дмитрий вернётся, и [после этого] мы все будем ждать вас в его кабинете.* || То есть очерёдность и следственность событий значительно важнее, чем факт, что всё это будет происходить вечером.

Но теоретически автор может и не ставить запятую — на основании того, что оба события происходят вечером. Тогда не будет подчёркиваться следственность событий — а в тексте она чётко выражена, и пунктуация должна быть соответствующей. Удачным и естественным такой вариант назвать нельзя.

И ещё, в большинстве примеров с общим элементом части равноправны — их можно поменять местами.