# Запятая в сложном предложении, есть ли что-то общее

Tags: запятые

В областном правительстве нашу инициативу поддержали(,) и уже есть предварительная договоренность по этому вопросу.
Нужна ли запятая в скобках?

Comment: Да, нужна. Это сложносочинённое предложение, поэтому между его частями перед И ставится запятая. Первая часть - неопределённо-личное односоставное предложение. Вторая часть - двусоставное предложение. Детерминанта здесь нет.

Comment: @Екатерина Автора вопроса смущает потенциальный общий элемент "в областном правительстве".

Comment: Если ответ будет в виде ОТВЕТА, то смогу отметить его полезность и решение вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверим, общий ли там элемент:
*В областном правительстве уже есть предварительная договоренность по этому вопросу.*
Нет, так не звучит. Договорённость есть не в правительстве, а в общем.

Тем более здесь сильное следствие (его принято отображать пунктуационно):
*В областном правительстве нашу инициативу поддержали, и [, как следствие,] уже есть предварительная договоренность по этому вопросу.*

Вывод: запятая нужна.

Comment: "как следствие" - согласен, но: "уже есть предварительная договоренность по этому вопросу" не в общем, а С правительством (конечно, не в правительстве). Вполне может быть общим членом, замену предлога можно отнести к разговорному стилю(?).

Comment: Даже в разговорном стиле нельзя так делать (так заменять предлоги), оно не воспринимается. Первостепенная задача разговорного стиля — чтобы было понятно. Например, мне не было понятно, что договорённость с правительством. Понял, что с кем-то из тех, кто поддержал. А она может быть и с теми, кто занимается этим делом (не с теми, кто поддержал в правительстве). "В общем" — потому что не сказано, с кем именно.

Comment: Ну... Буду думать (решать).

Comment: Следствие способно разрушать связь с общим элементом, а такую сомнительную — уж точно.

Comment: Уговорили : ), спасибо!

Comment: Это ещё несложный случай с общим фрагментом, смотрите [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468311), там хардкор. И [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457430) ещё реально сложный случай.