# Если вам удалось заполучить его раньше, то это явная ошибка(,) и она подлежит исправлению

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, ссп, и

Писал текст в контексте разговора об ошибке онлайновой игры.
Одна фраза заставила крепко задуматься (привожу "один в один", ибо даже небольшое изменение вызывает у меня уже другие эмоции).

***Если вам удалось заполучить его [артефакт] раньше, то это явная ошибка(,) и она подлежит исправлению.***

Очень не хочется ставить указанную запятую. Видимо, потому, что "это явная ошибка" и "она подлежит исправлению" воспринимаются как однородные придаточные. Но грамматика вроде бы не позволяет сделать такой разбор. Я чего-то недопонимаю?

***Короче, можно ли без запятой – и на каком основании?***

Answer (score 5):

Мне думается, что запятую ставить не следует (и не хочется, Вы правы).

Часть после первой запятой является сложносочиненным предложением, а первая часть – общим придаточным условия.

[**Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133) (Розенталь)

> 2. Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
>    <...>
>    *2)* Общей может быть придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения: *Уже совсем рассвело **и** народ стал подниматься, когда я вернулся в свою комнату* (Л. Т.); *Когда Аню провожали домой, то уже светало **и** кухарки шли на рынок* (Ч.); *Когда он вернулся в залу, сердце его билось **и** руки дрожали так заметно…* (Ч.)...

Поразмыслив, хочу дополнить ответ, так как появились сомнения: а является ли всё-таки придаточное общим? Ведь связь с последним предложением вообще не просматривается и не читается: "*Если вам удалось заполучить его [артефакт] раньше, то она [ошибка] подлежит исправлению*". Это последнее предложение относится только к "*это явная ошибка*". Поэтому однозначно ответить на вопрос о запятой для меня пока проблематично (весы склонились в сторону её нужности).

Comment: Вот, теперь вы правы. Радует, что я не против всех.

Comment: *так как появились сомнения: а является ли всё-таки придаточное общим* - у меня они с самого начала появилсь. Потому и вопрос возник. По тому смыслу, который я хотел вложить - как раз не является (см. мой комментарий под ответом Екатерины). Но это это все-таки не совсем грамматика.

Comment: А меня радует, что вы, пусть и совсем не моими словами. но внятно сформулировали суть моих сомнений, чего мне самому не всегда, увы, удается.

Comment: Спасибо за интересный вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

***Если вам удалось заполучить его [артефакт] раньше, то это явная ошибка и она подлежит исправлению.***

Придаточное предложение является общим для двух простых предложений второй части, соединённых союзом *И*. Вторая часть подчинительного союза (если...)*ТО* присоединяет это сложносочинённое предложение. Запятая перед И не ставится.

Ср.: ***Это явная ошибка и она подлежит исправлению (при каком условии?),*** ***если вам удалось заполучить его [артефакт] раньше.***

Comment: Екатерина, если оно так, то вопросов нет. Но убедите меня сначала, что придаточное относится и ко второй части. С точки зрения грамматики это какой-то пердимонокль получается. По смыслу-то фразы ошибка подлежит исправлению в любом случае, безотносительно к тому, найден тот артефакт или нет. ------ Или это непонятно по моей формулировке? Тогда фраза подлежит переделке, но это другой вопрос

Comment: @behemothus *По смыслу-то фразы ошибка подлежит исправлению в любом случае, безотносительно к тому, найден тот артефакт или нет* — не совсем, если артефакт не найден, то и исправлять нечего. Без запятой воспринимается, что именно эта ошибка подлежит исправлению, а с запятой — что любая такая ошибка (допущенная и другими), то есть общий смысл.

Answer (score 2):

Без запятой можно, но гораздо лучше с ней.

*Если вам удалось заполучить его [артефакт] раньше, то это явная ошИбка, и она подлежит исправлению.* || Естественно звучит логическое ударение.

Там естественно присоединение:
*Если вам удалось заполучить его [артефакт] раньше, то это явная ошИбка, и эта ошибка подлежит исправлению.* || Добавляется информация.

Похожий пример Розенталя:
*Вдали по-прежнему машет крыльями мельница, и всё ещё она похожа на маленького человечка, размахивающего руками.* || Удачно присоединение. Пусть там и есть общее.

Слово "ошибка" надо подчеркнуть логическим ударением — чтобы человек осознал, насколько это плохо.

Здесь важно то, как оно будет читаться. Не следует считать, что запятая ни на что не влияет.

Без запятой нет никаких эмоций, будто всё равно, что это ошибка.

Update:
Без запятой всё-таки допустимо. В процессе чтения "*и она подлежит исправлению*" об ошибке уже известно.
*Если вам удалось заполучить артефакт раньше, то содеянное [ошибка] подлежит исправлению.* || Звучит нормально, ведь об ошибке уже известно.
Тогда получается, что если артефакт не найден, то такая ошибка не подлежит исправлению. Но автор хочет сказать, что в любом случае нужно исправлять такое. А запятая как раз делает эту мысль независимой от условия.

Update 2:
Здесь всё гораздо сложнее. Возьмём похожие примеры:
*Если ты приедешь, то нужно подписать документы.* || Подписать в любом случае нужно. То не условие.
*Если пришлось сдаться, то это очень плохо.* || Сдаваться в любом случае плохо, не зависимо от того, как сложится у кого-то там.
*Если вы хотите так поступить, то так нельзя.* || Нельзя в любом случае, хочет он или нет. Здесь нет условия.
*Если посмотреть оригинальный текст, то там использован глагол.* || Глагол по-любому там использован, даже если не смотреть оригинальный текст. Полный вариант:
*Если посмотреть оригинальный текст, то можно заметить, что там использован глагол.*
*Если вам удалось заполучить артефакт раньше, то это явная ошибка.* || Удалось или нет, а заполучение артефакта раньше — в любом случае ошибка. Это не совсем условие, и это даже может восприниматься на слух (как у меня).

Похоже на то, что это разговорное упрощение. Полный вариант должен звучать как-то так:
*Если вам удалось заполучить артефакт раньше, то надо сказать, что это явная ошибка.*
Или можно так:
*Если вам удалось заполучить артефакт раньше, то вы совершили ошибку.* || Лучше всего.

Comment: Вы знаете, в данном я бы вообще не хотел, чтобы эмоции играли какую-то роль в объяснении пунктуации. Я-то говоря об "эмоциях" имел в виду совсем не это, а всего лишь моё отношение к выбранной формулировке.

Comment: Надо, чтобы оно нормально читалось, а не так, как говорит робот, которому фиолетово. Это не по-русски.