# Кнопка легко нажимается, девушка легко одевается

Tags: грамотная-речь

Кнопка легко нажимае**тся**. На кнопку легко нажать. Мы совершаем действия с кнопкой.

Девушка легко одевае**тся**. Девушка сама легко одевается. Девушка совершает действия с собой.

В обоих случаях глагол заканчивается на **тся**. Но смысл немного отличается. Какое тут правило работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в одушевлённости:
*девушка одевает себя = одевается;

кукла одевается девушкой*. || Ср.: *кнопка нажимается девушкой*.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь нет никакого "правила".

Возвратная частица "ся" имеет в русском языке несколько значений (по разным системам - от 6 до 10).
Вот тут более или менее полный список:
[Возвратный суффикс "ся"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8229)

В первом вашем примере "ся" придает глаголу страдательное значение (и ничего больше), во втором - классическая возвратность - перевод действия на себя (хотя с некоторым дополнительным значением, но это не принципиально).
Какая из семантических реализаций имеет место в каждом конкретном случае, наперед сказать нельзя, только убедившись (при необходимости - по словарю) в значении глагола. А иногда без контекста и не угадаешь

Comment: Я надеялся, что хоть кто-то удалит свой ответ, прочитав Ваш. Но нет — уже пошли свежие обсуждения в комментариях.

Comment: А, заметил — там даже один из "глубоких" ответов появился уже после Вашего.

Comment: @grizzly Увы... Давно замечено, что в инете уровень любой дискуссионной площадки (в истинном смысле слова "дискуссия") рано или поздно падает до уровня мелкой детсадовской потасовки, если не целенаправленно не прилагать усилий по поддержанию этого уровня.  Видимо, что-то подобное и происходит сейчас (по моим оценкам - года два, два с половиной) на rus.stackexchange. Мне всё меньше и меньше хочется давать подробные и выверенные в научном плане ответы - их просто некому читать.  Похоже, что не мне одному.

Comment: @JimKorbett Не возражаете, если я не буду отвечать на вопросы, не имеющие отношения к предмету обсуждения? А называть вы можете как хотите, не так еще обзывали, обычно я таких авторов просто игнорирую.

Answer (score 1):

**1. ОТВЕТ НА ВОПРОС**

(1) Девушка легко одевается. Девушка сама легко одевается. Девушка совершает действия с собой.

(2) Кнопка легко нажимается. На кнопку легко нажать. Мы совершаем действия с кнопкой.

Кажется, что во втором случае мы имеем пассивный залог, но это не так. Там мы используем **возвратные глаголы** (или глаголы **возвратного залога**).

Смысл приведенных предложений с такими глаголами действительно различен, хотя возвратность в обоих случаях обозначена частицей СЯ. Существует **несколько разрядов возвратных глаголов**, их характеристика дается в грамматических справочниках.

(1) ***Девушка легко одевается*** (в легкую, нетеплую  одежду). Собственно-возвратное действие. Субъект и объект действия совпадают: здесь субъект, выраженный подлежащим (обычно это одушевл. сущ.), **направляет действие на самого себя**.

ОДЕВАТЬСЯ, - нсв. 1. к Одеть – одеться. 2. Носить одежду того или иного фасона, качества и т.п. О. изящно, со вкусом.

(2) ***Кнопка легко нажимается.*** В этом случае глагол ХАРАКТЕРИЗУЮЩЕ-КАЧЕСТВЕННОГО значения называет действие **как характерную для субъекта склонность или способность** подвергаться какому-либо воздействию. Нитки плохие, рвутся; машина хорошо заводится; фарфор легко бьется; кофе плохо растворяется

**2. ГРАММАТИЧЕСКАЯ СПРАВКА**

АКТИВНЫЙ И ПАССИВНЫЙ ЗАЛОГ

Одна и та же ситуация, в которой участвуют субъект и прямой объект, описывается двумя способами, а именно:  активный оборот: рабочие строят дом; пассивный оборот: дом строится рабочими. Активный и пассивный залоги имеют только личные п е р е х о д н ы е глаголы (безличные и непереходные глаголы стоят вне залога).

**ВОЗВРАТНЫЙ ЗАЛОГ**

В этом случае субъект совершает активное действие, направленное на себя, прямой объект при этом отсутствует. **Частные**  значения возвратности указаны в грамматике.

ВОЗВРАТНЫЕ ГЛАГОЛЫ ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНОГО ЗАЛОГА (материал из Грамматики-80, для переходных глаолов)
http://rusgram.narod.ru/1455-1489.html

§ 1469. Возвратные глаголы, мотивированные ПЕРЕХОДНЫМИ глаголами, распределяются по нескольким лексико-грамматическим разрядам.

(1) **В ГЛАГОЛАХ СОБСТВЕННО-ВОЗВРАТНОГО ЗНАЧЕНИЯ** субъект и объект действия совпадают: субъект, выраженный подлежащим (обычно это сущ. одушевл.), **направляет действие на самого себя.** Это – глаголы со знач. физического действия: мыться, умываться, одеваться, раздеваться, обуваться, разуваться, причесываться, бриться, белиться, румяниться, кутаться, гримироваться;

(2) Глаголы ВЗАИМНО-ВОЗВРАТНОГО значения выражают взаимное (совместное, направленное друг на друга) действие нескольких субъектов: целоваться, обниматься (целовать, обнимать друг друга), встречаться, видеться, знаться (разг.), мириться, ссориться, шептаться.

(3) Глаголы КОСВЕННО-ВОЗВРАТНОГО значения называют действие, совершаемое субъектом в своих интересах; это значит, что субъект совершает действие для себя самого, но ни в самом глаголе, ни в его синтаксических связях это значение специально не выражается. Таковы глаголы прибираться, укладываться, строиться, построиться, запасаться, устраиваться; Хорь обстроился, накопил деньжонку (Тург.);

(4) ГЛАГОЛЫ АКТИВНО-БЕЗОБЪЕКТНОГО значения при потенциально-качественном употреблении глаголов несов. вида (см. § 1447) называют (как правило, в формах наст. вр.) действие как постоянное и характерное свойство субъекта, его отличительную черту: крапива жжется, корова бодается, собака кусается, кошки царапаются.

(5) **Глаголы ХАРАКТЕРИЗУЮЩЕ-КАЧЕСТВЕННОГО значения** называют (при тех же условиях, что и в п. 4) действие как характерную для субъекта **склонность или способность подвергаться какому-либо воздействию**: нитки плохие, рвутся; машина хорошо заводится; фарфор легко бьется; кофе плохо растворяется. Подлежащим при таких глаголах выражается субъект – носитель свойства, характерного признака.

(6) Глаголы ОБЩЕВОЗВРАТНОГО ЗНАЧЕНИЯ называют действие, замкнутое в сфере субъекта как его состояние: сердиться, тревожиться, удивляться, радоваться, томиться, пугаться, беспокоиться, веселиться, печалиться. И т.д.

Comment: С возвращением. Уезжали куда-то?

Comment: Спасибо! Вас вот решила навестить.  Как вам здесь работается,  с грамматикой всё получается? Что же вы нам про возвратный залог ничего не рассказали, пришлось вот дополнить.  Так что  дружите с классической и современной грамматикой, и будет вам тогда счастье и успех.

Comment: А мне хотелось объяснить просто и лаконично, на примерах, безо всяких закрученных формулировок, терминов и т.п. Кстати, крутость справочников Розенталя в том, что его примеры объясняют лучше, чем сами правила. Вот прикол: уже не отвечаю, и 8 последних вопросов стоят без ответов, все посваливали. Или все заняты, или естественный отбор, как вы говорили. Вы просматривали все вопросы, или мне скинуть список самых полезных на почту?

Comment: Как раз вопрос по грамматике: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468356 Видите подвох?

Comment: Ставите одушевленность против возвратного залога?  Проигрышная партия.  Отвечающие опять пропали? Вероятно, ваше красноречие  оказалось вне конкуренции. Но это как версия, а  в общем-то вопрос философский.  Я здесь просматриваю только интересные для проекта вопросы, а их мало. А чтобы  с лексикой разбираться, надо тему произведения хорошо знать – редактировать философские трактаты и психологические этюды по одному предложению – вещь неблагодарная.

Comment: Если посмотреть оригинальный текст, то там использован глагол: На площадке стояла девчонка — вроде бы ровесница, но из-за яркой куртки и задорных косичек выглядела она младше Кларочки, учившейся в третьем классе. Этот вариант выглядит более корректно, а  в приведенном предложении союз НО перед причастным оборотом  смотрится не на месте.

Comment: Разве может неодушевлённое что-то делать себе? Нет. А вопросов крутых штук пять было. И как обычно, о таких вещах и сам задумывался. А мне не удалось найти оригинал. Мне показалось, что надо так: *ровесница [Кларочки], но выглядевшая младше Кларочки*. То есть чтобы грамматически относилось и к "ровесница". Если говорим о ровеснице, то надо сразу сказать кого: *На площадке стояла девчонка — вроде бы ровесница Кларочки, учившейся в третьем классе, но из-за яркой куртки и задорных косичек выглядела она младше.* Иначе надо ждать, пока станет ясно, нарушение стилистики.

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, включу его в свой ответ здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468311

Comment: Разве может неодушевлённое что-то делать себе? Это вы про кнопку? Но здесь возвратный глагол выражает не действие, а способность к действию.

Comment: Про всё. Ну кнопка точно не может сама нажиматься. Да и словари не позволяют: нажимать — надавливать на что-либо.

Comment: Вам не надо состав орфографической комиссии? https://www.ruslang.ru/chleny-orfograficheskoy-komissii-ran

Comment: Спасибо, Что-то там академиков маловато, где-то от нуля до одного. В 1956 году их побольше было.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл неважен. Здесь исключительно синтаксис.

*Нажимается* и *одевается* — глаголы в форме 3-го лица множественного числа. Окончание -тся (классически проверяется вопросом *что делает?*)

Если было бы «*кнопка может легко нажиматься*» и «*девушка может легко одеваться*», то *нажиматься* и *одеваться* были бы неопределёнными формами глагола (инфинитив). Окончание -ться (классически проверяется вопросом *что сделать?*).

Comment: Смысл важен. В ответе желательно было хоть что-то сказать про *возвратные глаголы* и привести основные значения. [Ссылка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) в помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда глубокий вопрос

В обоих случаях объект нажимает/одевает сам себя. Но делает он это, возможно, при помощи кого-то, что выражается творительным падежом.

Сравните:

```
Рычаг поворачивается машинистом. (поворачивает себя при помощи машиниста)
Я поворачиваюсь к машинисту. (поворачиваю себя сама)

Девушка одевается своими родителями. (одевает себя при помощи родителей)
Чайник кипятится. (кипятит сам себя) 
Чайник кипятится паяльной лампой. (кипятит себя при помощи паяльной лампы).
Кнопка самопроизвольно нажимается. (нажимает сама себя).
```

Comment: Рычаг, увы, не может себя поворачивать. *Кнопка самопроизвольно нажимается. (нажимает сама себя)*  — словарь: *нажимать* — надавливать на что-либо. Кнопка надавливает на саму себя... У неё нет чем надавить.