# Грамматическая ошибка в предложении

Tags: грамматика

Скажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли построено предложение, нет ли в нём грамматической ошибки?

*На площадке стояла девчонка — вроде бы ровесница, но из-за яркой куртки и задорных косичек выглядевшая младше Кларочки, учившейся в третьем классе.*